# Using ModelBuilder to iterate through and export to single layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, export

I have a geodatabase that has multiple layers, the layers all have some of same attribute names. I am trying to use ModelBuilder to iterate through the GDB and export all polygon features that have the same attribute name into a single layer.

For example, I have a buildings, parks, and structure layers in a GDB all three have the same attribute names "facilityNumber", "facilityIDNumber", and "facilityName" among others that are different for each layer. I want to export just the shape and the attribute information that is the same across all features into one single polygon layer.

Comment: Try the merge tool and limit the field mapping? A single tool.